# VHDL - nested if statements

Tags: if-statement, process, nested, vhdl

I have a process defined in vhdl like this(I know some of the conditions in if statements are unnecessary but I'm ignoring that for now):

```
LSPflag : process(xcolumn, yrow, picture_q_s) -- output of process depends on xcolumn and yrow
    variable RGB : RGB_type; -- output colors
    variable x, y, zx,zy : integer; -- renamed xcolumn and yrow
     variable isPicture:boolean;
    begin
        x:=to_integer(xcolumn); y:=to_integer(yrow); -- convert to integer
        zy:= To_integer(unsigned(xyoffset));
        zx:= (To_integer(unsigned(xyoffset))*XSIZE)/YSIZE;
        RGB:=BLACK;
        if zy>360 then
        --do stuff1 with if statements
        end if;
        if zy>240 then 
        --do stuff2 with if statements
        end if;
        if zy>120 then
        --do stuff3 with if statements
        else
            isPicture:= x>=EMBORGX+centerx-zx and x<EMBORGX+MEMROWSIZE+centerx-zx and y>=EMBORGY+centery+zy and y<EMBORGY+MEMROWCOUNT+centery+zy;               
            if isPicture and picture_q_s = '1'  then--bottomleft corner
                RGB:=YELLOW or RGB;
            end if;
            if  y*XSIZE<=-YSIZE*x+YSIZE*XSIZE+(centery-zy)*XSIZE+(centerx-zx)*YSIZE and  x>=centerx-zx and x<=XSIZE+centerx-zx and y>=centery-zy and y<=YSIZE+centery-zy then--upperleft corner
                RGB:=WHITE or RGB;
            end if;
            if  y*XSIZE>-YSIZE*x+YSIZE*XSIZE+(centery-zy)*XSIZE+(centerx+zx)*YSIZE and x>=centerx+zx and x<=XSIZE+centerx+zx and y>=centery-zy and y<=YSIZE+centery-zy and y*XSIZE<YSIZE*x-(2*zy)*XSIZE then--upperright corner
                RGB:=RED or RGB;
            end if;
            if y*XSIZE>-YSIZE*x+YSIZE*XSIZE+(centery+zy)*XSIZE+(centerx+zx)*YSIZE and  x>=centerx+zx and x<=XSIZE+centerx+zx and y>=centery+zy and y<=YSIZE+centery+zy and y*XSIZE>YSIZE*x then--bottomright corner
                RGB:=BLUE or RGB;
            end if;
            if isPicture then
                picture_address_s <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned((y-EMBORGY-centery-zy)*MEMROWSIZE + (x-EMBORGX-centerx+zx), picture_address_s'LENGTH));
            else 
                picture_address_s <=(others=>'0'); 
            end if;
        end if;
        VGA_R<=RGB.R; VGA_G<=RGB.G; VGA_B<=RGB.B;
    end process;
```

I wanted the program to stop checking the 4 outer conditions after it finds the true one.
If I write it like above, it works but It checks first of the three conditions always no matter what.
I was trying to do something like this:

```
        if zy>360 then
        --do stuff with if statements1          
        else if zy>240 then 
        --do stuff with if statements2 
        else if zy>120 then
        --do stuff with if statements3 
        else
            isPicture:= x>=EMBORGX+centerx-zx and x<EMBORGX+MEMROWSIZE+centerx-zx and y>=EMBORGY+centery+zy and y<EMBORGY+MEMROWCOUNT+centery+zy;               
            if isPicture and picture_q_s = '1'  then--bottomleft corner
                RGB:=YELLOW or RGB;
            end if;
            if  y*XSIZE<=-YSIZE*x+YSIZE*XSIZE+(centery-zy)*XSIZE+(centerx-zx)*YSIZE and  x>=centerx-zx and x<=XSIZE+centerx-zx and y>=centery-zy and y<=YSIZE+centery-zy then--upperleft corner
                RGB:=WHITE or RGB;
            end if;
            if  y*XSIZE>-YSIZE*x+YSIZE*XSIZE+(centery-zy)*XSIZE+(centerx+zx)*YSIZE and x>=centerx+zx and x<=XSIZE+centerx+zx and y>=centery-zy and y<=YSIZE+centery-zy and y*XSIZE<YSIZE*x-(2*zy)*XSIZE then--upperright corner
                RGB:=RED or RGB;
            end if;
            if y*XSIZE>-YSIZE*x+YSIZE*XSIZE+(centery+zy)*XSIZE+(centerx+zx)*YSIZE and  x>=centerx+zx and x<=XSIZE+centerx+zx and y>=centery+zy and y<=YSIZE+centery+zy and y*XSIZE>YSIZE*x then--bottomright corner
                RGB:=BLUE or RGB;
            end if;
            if isPicture then
                picture_address_s <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned((y-EMBORGY-centery-zy)*MEMROWSIZE + (x-EMBORGX-centerx+zx), picture_address_s'LENGTH));
            else 
                picture_address_s <=(others=>'0'); 
            end if;
        end if;
```

But then it is uncompilable and it says if statement is expected near text process.

Comment: This looks more like C-code then VHDL to me. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: I didn't want to show it here since it isn't really relevant to the issue in my opinion, but I edited it in the post.

Comment: Your edit does not provide a  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: it is neither minimal, complete, nor verifiable. Your post is now showing the same code snippet three times. We cannot simulate it, so we cannot see your issue. You're just asking us to debug highly integrated code without any comments. I'm sorry, but that will take me too much time.

Comment: You have a lot of `else if` lines which open new nested `if` statements. you probably meant to use `elsif` which doesn't. The consequence of this is a lot of missing `end if` statements so the parser finds `end process` in the wrong place (deep in the nested `if`s.) Which is what the error message (had you bothered to post it) was trying to say. That version, with corrected syntax, is probably what you were trying to reach.

Comment: @JHBonarius hmm okay, I'll try to express myself in a different way

Comment: @BrianDrummond omg! yes I can't believe I missed that, its true the problem was I wrote else if instead of elsif

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). `I wanted the program to stop checking the 4 outer conditions after it finds the true one.` 'I want' isn't a specific problem statement. IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.8 If statement *An if statement selects for execution one or none of the enclosed sequences of statements, depending on the value of one or more corresponding conditions.* Use `elsif` making the current four if statements one if statement. You end up with an ordered priority.

Answer (score 0):

As BrianDrummond remminded me, the problem was i wrote 'else if' instead of elsif.